# How can I see how much my CPU is being throttled?

Tags: windows, diagnostic, cpu-throttling

Windows has a feature which can be set from the *Power Options* menu where the CPU is automatically throttled according to usage in order to save power.

How can I view this throttling in real time? For instance, is the `CPU Usage` in `Windows Task Manager` a good indicator?

Answer (score 7):

Windows 7 has a tool called *Resource Monitor* which shows this. You can launch it by pressing `Windows+R` to bring up the *Run* dialog, then type `perfmon.exe /res` and press `Enter`.

[image]

On the *CPU* panel, the *Maximum Frequency* (small blue graph) shows at what power the CPU is currently operating.

Comment: Can someone confirm that this is correct? I will wait for other answers until then.

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @Xavierjazz I have tried it: When I increase the minimum activity under *Power Options* the *Maximum Frequency* appears to increase. However, even with the minimum set to 5%, it jumps all over the place quite a bit any way, so I hesitate to treat this experiment as conclusive.

Comment: This question started to interest me as well. So have you figured out if it is the case? Does the *Maximum Frequency* drop when the CPU is being throttled?

Answer (score 4):

I like using [CoreTemp](http://alcpu.com/CoreTemp/). It runs as admin, but it's free and signed by [GlobalSign](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GlobalSign) in the authors name.

What's cool is seeing how throttling conserves energy. Here's an example:

[image: Throttled][image: Unthrottled]

Comment: Does Core Temp show the current throttle level? I thought it only showed load (assuming these two aren't the same thing).

Comment: @Superbest Well it shows a couple of throttles, the CPU multiplier and voltage level. The multiplier is the second multiplcand in `Frequency`, I'm not sure what the correct term for the first is anymore. The voltage is next to `VID`. With recent Intel chips, if you pay very close attention you might notice some cores get throttled while one or more gets unthrolled (boosted) on things like single-threaded workloads.